# QlikSense API - .Net SDK - web application

Tags: .net, web-applications, sdk, qliksense

In my .Net SDK app I load an app and visualizations from Qlik Server.

Is there a way to send the visualizations from the .Net SDK app to my angularjs web application on Azure cloud, using REST probably?

Answer (score 1):

you can use PhantomJS or SlimerJS to retrieve screenshots of your visualizations

Comment: Thanks Idriss. I hope to get more mashup support, like dynamic filtering and selections.